# delete row if ID is same in another table

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables (Table1 and Table2.) I want to delete all rows in table2 if the id exsits in table1

Code so far:

```
DELETE a.id, a.car, a.boat 
FROM Table2 a 
LEFT JOIN Table1 b ON b.id = a.id
```

tables:

- table 1: `id, car, boat`
- table 2: `id, car, boat` (delete if ID is same value as ID in table1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DELETE Table2
  FROM Table2
  JOIN Table1 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

Comment: why you say that? Is there a better way to do it without a join??

Answer (score 5):

```
Delete from table2 where table2.ID IN (select id from table1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Test this in a rollback transaction first (good habit to always do this with deletes)

```
DELETE FROM table2
    WHERE table2.id IN (SELECT table1.id FROM table1)
```